# A way to return an Optional value if present without saving it or deriving it twice?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

I'd like to do something like the following, where `x` would be returned *from the containing function* and *not* "continue processing" if the optional is present:

```
stuff().that().returns().optional().ifPresent(x -> return x);
// otherwise continue processing
...
return alternateResult;
```

Something like this would be ok, too:

```
if (stuff().that().returns().optional().isPresent()) {
    return thatResult;
}
// otherwise continue processing
...
return alternateResult;
```

But ideas like these don't work: `return` inside the lambda just returns from the lambda, and in the 2nd case, I don't have the value back inside the closure after checking `isPresent()`.  Is there a more concise idiom I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can do the rest of the processing inside a lambda you could use [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
return stuff().that().returns().optional().orElseGet(() -> {
    ...
    return alternateResult;
});
```

Comment: Or maybe move the processing to another method, which might be invoked by `orElseGet`.

Comment: If you already have a value in a captured variable, like `x`, will `.orElse(x)` work too?

Comment: Moving the return outside is a nice idea, and I think this is generally better, thanks.  I will say I think it's a drawback in some cases that the alternate result is processed "inside" the optional check.  I.e., in the case that inspired the question, the optional check is an oddball case, which circumvents the main calculation that gives the method its name.)  I might go either way, then, depending what I'm thinking of as the main pathway.

Answer (score 1):

The best I've come up with so far.  Is this the best there is?

```
Optional<ExplicitType> maybeResult = stuff().that().returns().optional();
if (maybeResult.isPresent()) {
    return maybeResult.get();
}
// otherwise continue processing
...
return alternateResult;
```